# IPv4 Connectivity Issues w/ Network Manager

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am having a weird time with IPv4 and NetworkManager.  All my settings are defaulted in NetworkManager.  When I connect with NetworkManager, I do not get any IPv4 connectivity (IPv6 only), so only a select amount of websites load.

However, if I edit /etc/network/interfaces to manually add the following lines:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then everything works fine, but the connection is not managed through network manager.

Any idea of what could be going on?  Also, another weird symptom is that if I let the connection run with NetworkManager, after a while, I end up with my entire local network (i.e., everything hooked up to my router) having IPv4 issues.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Also, before anyone asks, I did try this fix: https://askubuntu.com/questions/584321/ipv4-is-not-getting-configured-on-ubuntu-in-a-dualstack-ipv4-ipv6-network?rq=1 .  The result was that the connection does not complete (i.e., it's always trying to connect without success).

Comment: There is some bug in NM. I have that problem too sometimes. If I disconnect and connect again, I get the IPV4 address.

Comment: Disconnect/Reconnect doesn't help me unfortunately.  I guess for now, I will just configure the interface manually and look for an update to NM.

Comment: Is DHCP set for IPV4 in NM?

Comment: Method: Automatic (DHCP) is the IPv4 setting (the default)

Comment: Look in the network definition (Wired Connection, or whatever) IPv4 tab. There's a setting something like "Must have IPv4 address to complete connection" (I'm doing this from memory) and checkmark it. Now see if you can get a proper IPv4 address when connecting. Report back.

Comment: Tried that already.  When that happens, no connection gets established.  Basically, from the looks of things I either get an IPv6 only connection or no connection at all when using NM.

Comment: Show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `ifconfig`. Edit that output into your question, not in comments, please.